# Scroll To Anchor Tag When using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout to populate a webpage in my project, and I want to be able to go to an anchor tag in the page that is bound to by a knockoutjs property. When when I hit this page from outside with an anchor tag, "Book/Main/1#mytag", it does not scroll to this tag I'm guessing because that tag does not exist on the page yet.

How can I hit this page from outside, let the page populate, then scroll to this anchor tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you `applyBindings`, you just need to clear and re-set `location.hash`.

```
// Save it
var scrollTag = location.hash;
// ... Define your vm and whatnot ...
ko.applyBindings(vm);
//clear hash
location.hash = '';
//re-set it
location.hash = scrollTag;
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6pe4yrp/1/)

Comment: you have included a link thath points to an SO question, instead of to a fiddle. pPlease, update it.

Comment: +1 To make this nearly perfect, you could add the content of the jsfiddle as a code snippet in your answer. Probably you've never used it, but it's quite similar to jsfiddle. You insert it with the last button of the second group, the one with the tags. jsfiddle editor is superior, but copying from jsfiddle to a code snippet take little time.

Comment: I've used the code snippet tool many times. Location-hash fiddling didn't work in the snippet tool, so I just linked the fiddle.